# Flask onButton pass string to a function

Tags: python, html, forms, button, flask

I was wondering if there was some way to pass info to a python function using flask. Here's the html in question:

```
<body>
<h1>Your Tags</h1>
<a href="/home">Home</a>
<style type="text/css">
        table, th, td{
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
</style>
<table>
    <th>Poster</th>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Item Name</th>  
  {% for line in contentitems %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{line.email_post}}</td>
      <td>{{line.post_time}}</td>
      <td>{{line.item_name}}</td>
      <td><form action="/accTag" method="GET">
            <!--button goes here-->
          </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
</body>
```

The page pulls a list of content items from a database for which the user has received a request to be tagged, and displays them as a table. The last column of every line should be a button that says "Accept Tag". When the user clicks it, I would like it to update the element in the database to show that the user has accepted the tag. However, I'm not sure how to pass the info back such that my Python code knows which element to update. Any ideas?